# console log object inside object after changing value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why is this happening?

```
var test_obj = {
    test: {}
};

test_obj.test.a = "hi";
console.log(test_obj);     // 1 a is 'hi'
test_obj.test.b = "bye";
console.log(test_obj);     // 2 b is not 'bye' but empty object
test_obj.test.b = {};
```

The console.log results are not expected for `test_obj.test.b`. Why is this happening, is printing console.log asynchronous?

This confused me because I have mousedown to do `test_obj.test.b` and console.log it, and mouseup to do `test_obj.test.b = {}`. I expected to find test_obj.test.b and its value, but both the key and value are not there. Also, `.test.b` also shows in the first console.log.

What can I do to make it what I expect?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of / related to [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for such a quick answer. `JSON.stringify(object)` solved it.